# No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'com.javatechig.todo'

Tags: android, android-xml

I am getting the compile error after imported the sample project.I am getting the error in menu.xml.

> error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in
>   package 'com.javatechig.todo'

**menu.xml:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.sqlitesample.MainActivity" >

    <item             ----->error line
        android:id="@+id/add_record"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/add_record"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>


    <item             ---->error line
        android:id="@+id/export_records"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_import_export"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/export_records"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: Refrence appcompat_v7 in yuor project...

Comment: @MD I added that already.but still error didn't resolved for me

Answer (score 3):

All above fix may not work in android studio .if you are using **ANDROID STUDIO USERS SEE HERE**...... use this fix

add

`xmlns:compat="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`

in menu tag instead of

`xmlns:compat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto "`

in **menu** tag.

Comment: Thanks, it works for me altough I'm using Eclipse and android-support-v4.jar

Comment: welcome bro ... but switch to android studio .. it's the time to do so

Answer (score 0):

Add ***"android-support-v7-appcompat.jar"*** to Android Private Libraries (in ***libs*** folder of project)

OR

Make sure your project's build target is set to Honeycomb (API level 11).

Comment: Have you changed build target version to 11 ?

Comment: `
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />`

Comment: If you are using that then it should get compiled. Is error changed ?

Comment: Try this or update your menu tag fields :  

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"/>

</menu>

Comment: remove only the android:showAsAction="always" solved my problem.Thank you for your help

Comment: This is not a solution, ***android:showAsAction*** introduced in Android 3.0 version so if you are using build version 11 (Android 3.0) or above then your project should get compiled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `android:showAsAction="always"` from `res/menu` folder from every **xml** file